# Query for: view users and permissions (roles) from root security folder (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users

On the Internet I found a lot of scripts how to display users and their permissions under a particular database (Security folder under table) - for example `sp_helpuser`.
Currently, however, I need to use a query to extract users and their permissions from the root of Security folder in Management Studio.

Can you please tell me how to extract users and permissions (roles) from this folder using the script?
Thank you all in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a script similar to this one...

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
GO
CREATE TABLE [TEMPDB].[DBO].[DB_ROLES]([DBNAME] [SYSNAME] ,
       [USERNAME] [SYSNAME] ,
       [DB_OWNER] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_ACCESSADMIN] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_SECURITYADMIN] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_DDLADMIN] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_DATAREADER] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_DATAWRITER] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_DENYDATAREADER] VARCHAR ,
       [DB_DENYDATAWRITER] VARCHAR ,
       [DT_CREATE] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
       [DT_UPDATE] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
       [DT_REPORT] [DATETIME] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__DBROLES__CUR_DAT__3A179ED3]  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) ) ON [PRIMARY] 
       GO
       INSERT INTO    [TEMPDB].[DBO].[DB_ROLES] 
       EXEC SP_MSFOREACHDB 'SELECT''?'' AS DBNAME, USERNAME, MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_OWNER''THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) 
       AS DB_OWNER,        MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_ACCESSADMIN ''   THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_ACCESSADMIN ,
       MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_SECURITYADMIN''  THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_SECURITYADMIN,
       MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_DDLADMIN''   THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_DDLADMIN,
       MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_DATAREADER''        THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_DATAREADER,
       MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_DATAWRITER''        THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_DATAWRITER,
       MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_DENYDATAREADER'' THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_DENYDATAREADER,
       MAX(CASE ROLENAME WHEN ''DB_DENYDATAWRITER'' THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS DB_DENYDATAWRITER,
       CREATEDATE, UPDATEDATE, GETDATE()
            FROM (SELECT B.NAME AS USERNAME, C.NAME AS ROLENAME, B.CREATEDATE, B.UPDATEDATE FROM [?].DBO.SYSMEMBERS A   JOIN [?].DBO.SYSUSERS  B  ON A.MEMBERUID = B.UID
            JOIN [?].DBO.SYSUSERS C ON A.GROUPUID = C.UID)S
            GROUP BY USERNAME, CREATEDATE, UPDATEDATE
            ORDER BY USERNAME' 
            SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME') AS [SERVERNAME], B.NAME AS [LOGINNAME], 
            CASE B.SYSADMIN  WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS SYSADMIN, CASE B.SECURITYADMIN WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS SECURITYADMIN, CASE B.SETUPADMIN  WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS SETUPADMIN, CASE B.PROCESSADMIN  WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS PROCESSADMIN, CASE B.DISKADMIN  WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS DISKADMIN, CASE B.DBCREATOR  WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS DBCREATOR, CASE B.BULKADMIN  WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS BULKADMIN, B.DBNAME AS [DEFAULT_DBNAME], 
            A.* INTO #LOGINS FROM [TEMPDB].[DBO].[DB_ROLES] A RIGHT JOIN MASTER..SYSLOGINS B ON A.USERNAME=B.NAME WHERE B.ISNTUSER=1
            SELECT * FROM #LOGINS ORDER BY [LOGINNAME]
            DROP TABLE  [TEMPDB].[DBO].[DB_ROLES] 
            DROP TABLE  #LOGINS

Comment: It is look good, but this script can´t show SQL server users - it show only Windows users. 
When i created tmp table #LOGINS, so I tried to skip the condition `WHERE B.ISNTUSER=1`. After that it show report also with SQL users, but i can´t see permisions to databases fot this SQL users.

Do you have any idea how edit script?